# Reference request - identity in central factorial numbers

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, factorial

Knuth (in [arXiv:math/9207222 [math.CA]](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9207222), page 10)  gives an odd polynomial identity like

$$n^{2m-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} (2k-1)! T(2m,2k) \binom{n+k-1}{2k-1},$$

where $T(m,k)$ is cental factorial numbers. However, the following identity holds as well

$$(2k-1)! T(2m,2k) = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^j \binom{2k}{j} (k-j)^{2m} \quad \quad (1.0)$$
Or by symmetry of binomial coefficients
$$(2k-1)! T(2m,2k) = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-j} \binom{2k}{k-j} j^{2m} \quad \quad (1.1)$$
The question: Is there any reference to identities (1.0), (1.1) ?

Alternative question: Prove the identities (1.0), (1.1)

PS It might seem that (1.0) is got from stirling numbers of second kind
PSS Bounty started

Comment: How did you got to 1.0?

Comment: Luschny, an editor of OEIS provided it here https://oeis.org/A303675, I just simplified it. However, he says it is folklore formula known thousands years, and doesn't give a direct reference

Comment: The phrase "central factorial numbers" is sufficiently obscure that it seems worth including the definition. They appear as coefficients in the following expansions: $$x^m =\sum_{k=1}^m T(m,k)x^{[k]},\qquad x^{[k]}=x(x+k/2-1)(x+k/2-2)\cdots (x+k/2+1).$$ Knuth states without proof that $T(m,k)=0$ if $m-k$ is odd, and on this basis deduces the first equation of the question.

Comment: Binomial coefficients:1000 to 2000 years old; the binomial theorem and Pascal's triangle: 500 years old; OEIS: thousands of years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some references: We find in

- *[Combinatorial Identities](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471722758)* by J. Riordan (1963), ch. 6.5 the formula (24):
  \begin{align*}
   k!T(n,k)=\sum_{j=0}\binom{k}{j}(-1)^j\left(\frac{1}{2}k-j\right)^n\tag{24}
   \end{align*}
- *[The divided central differences of zero](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/E36B78480B5E130BE2692BD633F87FE1/S0008414X00029278a.pdf/divided_central_differences_of_zero.pdf)* by  L. Carlitz and J. Riordan (1961) the formula (10a):
  \begin{align*}
   K_{rs} = \frac{1}{(2s)!}\sum_{t=0}^{2s}(-1)^t\binom{2s}{t}(s-t)^{2r+2}\tag{10a}
   \end{align*}
- *[Interpolation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GHQVON8)* by J.F. Steffenson (1927) section 58:

  The development of $x^r$ in *central factorials*
  \begin{align*}
   x^r=\sum_0^r x^{[\nu]}\frac{\delta^{\nu}0^r}{\nu!}
   \end{align*}
  leads  to **central differences of nothing**, that is
  \begin{align*}
   \delta^m0^r=\sum_0^m(-1)^{\nu}\binom{m}{\nu}\left(\frac{m}{2}-\nu\right)^r
   \end{align*}

*Comment:* The meaning of the left hand side $\delta^m0^r$ is given in the derivation below.

---

Here I'd like to show the derivation of (24) above following J. Riordan. It is based upon three ingredients: operators, a recurrence relation and Newton's formula.

**Operators:** We recall  the shift operator $E^a$ and the difference operator $\Delta$:

\begin{align*}
 E^af(x)&=f(x+a)\\
 \Delta f(x)&=f(x+1)-f(x)
 \end{align*}
 and introduce the *central difference operator* $\delta$:
 \begin{align*}
 \delta f(x)=f\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)-f\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)
 \end{align*}

> We can write the  $\delta$ operator using shift and difference operator as:
>   \begin{align*}
>  \delta f(x)&= \left(E^{\frac{1}{2}} - E^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)f(x)\tag{1}\\
>  &=\Delta E^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)=E^{\frac{1}{2}}\Delta f(x)\tag{2}\\
>  \end{align*}
>   We obtain from (1) by successive application of $\delta$ 
>   \begin{align*}
>  \delta^kf(x)&=\left(E^{\frac{1}{2}}-E^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^kf(x)\\
>  &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-1)^jE^{-\frac{j}{2}}E^{\frac{k-j}{2}}f(x)\\
>  &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-1)^jf\left(x-j+\frac{k}{2}\right)\tag{3}
>  \end{align*}

Note that (3) has already the shape of (24). So, this step looks promising and it's interesting to see how J. Riordan continues. The next step is to introduce the main actor.

**Central factorials:** We denote with $x^{[n]}$ the *central factorial* defined as

> \begin{align*}
>  x^{[n]}&=x\left(x+\frac{n}{2}-1\right)^{\underline{n-1}}\\
>  &=x\left(x+\frac{n}{2}-1\right)\left(x+\frac{n}{2}-2\right)\cdots\left(x+\frac{n}{2}-n+1\right)
>  \end{align*}
>    where we use Don Knuths notation for falling factorials $x^{\underline{n}}=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)$.
>
> The central factorials obey an important recurrence relation which is the key for all what follows. We have according to (2):
>   \begin{align*}
>  \delta x^{[n]}&=\Delta E^{-\frac{1}{2}}x^{[n]}\\
>  &=\Delta \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{[n]}\\
>  &=\Delta\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{n}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\underline{n-1}}\\
>  &=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\underline{n-1}}-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{n}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\underline{n-1}}\\
>  &=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{n}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\underline{n-2}}\\
>  &\qquad-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{n}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\underline{n-2}}\left(x+\frac{n}{2}-\frac{3}{2}-n+2\right)\\
>  &=nx^{[n-1]}\tag{4}
>  \end{align*}

The recurrence relation reminds us on $\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$ and we will use it accordingly.

**Newton's formula:**

We consider a series expansion of $f(x)$ in terms  of $x^{[n]}$ and apply the central difference operator $\delta$:

\begin{align*}
 f(x)&=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^{[n]}\\
 \delta^j f(x)&=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n\delta^j x^{[n]}=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n n^{\underline{j}}x^{[n-j]}\tag{5}\\
 \delta^j f(0)&=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n n^{\underline{j}}\delta_{n,j}=a_jj!\tag{6}
 \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (5) we apply the central difference operator $\delta$ $j$ times and use the recurrence relation (4).
- In (6) we evaluate $f(x)$ at $x=0$ using the *[Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)* symbol.

  > We obtain from (6) the following representation of Newton's formula:
  >   \begin{align*}
  >  f(x)&=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{[j]}}{j!}\delta^jf(0)\tag{7}
  >  \end{align*}
  >
  > The final step is setting $f(x)=x^n$ in (7), denoting the coefficients $a_k$ with $T(n,k)$ and obtain with (6)
  >   \begin{align*}
  >  x^n&=\sum_{k=0}^nT(n,k)x^{[k]}\\
  >  \delta^k0^n&=T(n,k)k!\tag{8}\\
  >  \end{align*}
  >   and using (3) we obtain from (8):
  >   \begin{align*}
  >  k!T(n,k)=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-1)^jf\left(\frac{1}{2}k-j\right)^n
  >  \end{align*}
  >   which is formula (24) and the claim follows.

Comment: Great answer, thank you !

Comment: @PKK: I've added a proof which might be interesting.

Comment: Exciting! This fulfills the answer.

Comment: @PKK: You're welcome!

Comment: @PKK: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. :-)

Comment: I thought bounty is moving automatically when answer is accepted, only today get notification like "set bounty manually" so it is. Answer is great and worthy to be awarded. Thanks

Comment: @PKK: I see. Everything's fine. You're welcome and thanks again.